# Isnull in where Clause

Tags: sql, isnull

SQL Server:

I'm trying to write something like this:

```
SELECT A.*, B.VALUE FROM A, B
      WHERE A.TYPE = B.TYPE
      AND B.VALUE = ISNULL(A.VALUE, '0000')
```

So basically, I want to search B and find where the TYPES match, and the Value field is = to the Value field in A. If it's not found, I want to search B for '0000' instead.

But It's not picking up rows where B.VALUE = '0000'
If I remove the IsNull and just put '0000', it does bring back the rows.

EDIT:
Here's a made up example:

```
SELECT * FROM #TEMP4 ORDER BY TYPE <BR/>
SELECT * FROM #TEMP5 ORDER BY TYPE
```

TEMP4:
TYPE-----VALUE 
A-----------1131 
A-----------1111 
A-----------0000 
B-----------0000 
B-----------1151 
C-----------1121

TEMP5:
TYPE-----VALUE 
A-----------1131 
B-----------1161

Desired result set: 
A-----------1131-------1131 
B-----------1161-------0000

```
SELECT A.*, B.VALUE FROM #TEMP5 A, #TEMP4 B
    WHERE A.TYPE = B.TYPE
    AND B.VALUE = ISNULL(A.VALUE, '0000')
```

This only brings back: 
A-----------1131-------1131

Comment: Maybe there is no row in `A` where `VALUE` is null or equal `VALUE` of `B`... are there any matching data in your tables?

Comment: If A.VALUE is NULL is A.TYPE also null?

Comment: What type of DB is this?

Comment: SQL server ----------------------

Answer (score 2):

What you are after is coalesce function:

```
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE EXISTS 
  (SELECT 'X' FROM B WHERE A.TYPE = B.TYPE
      AND B.VALUE = COALESCE(A.VALUE, '0000'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting anything from `B`, so I think the logic you want is:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM B
              WHERE A.TYPE = B.TYPE AND
                    (B.VALUE = A.VALUE OR B.VALUE = '0000')
             );
```

Comment: I tried that. That's going to return rows for both A.Value and '0000'. I only want one or the other.

Comment: This answer may solve your problem if you update the subquery to `WHERE B.TYPE = A.TYPE AND (B.VALUE = A.VALUE OR (B.VALUE = '0000' AND A.VALUE IS NULL))`... try this, please.

Comment: This will still return both rows... there is a row where A.VALUE = B.VALUE and a row where B.VALUE = '0000'. I only want one or the other, I don't want both.

Comment: I edited original post, hope my question makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

This query solves your problem. It selects through a subquery the highest value available for a matching type.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    A.*, 
    (
      SELECT TOP 1 VALUE 
      FROM #TEMP4  
      WHERE 1=1
        AND TYPE = A.TYPE 
        AND VALUE IN (A.VALUE, '0000')
      ORDER BY VALUE DESC
    ) BVALUE
  FROM #TEMP5 A
) z 
WHERE BVALUE IS NOT NULL
```